# Cannot register bcache backing device: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, bcache

When I try to register my bcache backing device:

```
echo $backing | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register
```

I get `Invalid argument`

The cache device is already registered.

Answer (score 2):

First,  try some clean-up:

```
echo $cset_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/pendings_cleanup
echo $backing_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/pendings_cleanup
```

Use `bcache-super-show` to get the uuids.

Then try again to register:

```
echo $cset_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register
echo $backing_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register
```

The cache uuid should exist in /dev/fs/bcache if the cache device is successfully registered.

If `bcache-super-show` says that that the backing `dev.data.cache_state` state is `clean` and the `cset.uuid` consists only of zeros, the bcache device is in the invalid state and must be recreated. [[source](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018621)]

However, if clean, you could try force-starting the backing device without cache device:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/block/$dev/bcache/running
```